# Equation constraints with scipy least_squares

Tags: optimization, scipy, least-squares

I'm trying to use least square to minimize a loss function by changing x,y,z. My problem is nonlinear hence why i chose scipy least_squares. The general structure is:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
def loss_func(x, *arguments):
 # plug x's and args into an arbitrary equation and return loss
 return loss # loss here is an array

# x_arr contains x,y,z
res = least_squares(loss_func, x_arr, args=arguments)
```

I am trying to constraint x,y,z by: x-y = some value, z-y = some value. How do I go about doing so? The scipy least_squares documentation only provided bounds. I understand I can create bounds like 0<x<5. However, my constraints is an equation and not a constant bound. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your may need to use a general purpose NLP (Nonlinear Programming) solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever stumble on this question, I've figured out how to overcome this issue. Since least_squares does not have constraints, it is best to just use **linear programming** with scipy.optimize.minimize. Since the `loss_func` returns an array of residuals, we can use L1 norm (as we want to minimize the absolute difference of this array of residuals).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def loss_func(x, *arguments):
 # plug x's and args into an arbitrary equation and return loss (loss is an array)
 return np.linalg.norm(loss, 1)
```

The bounds can be added to scipy.optimize.minimize fairly easily:)